# Calling twice a function overwrites previous results stored separately

Tags: python, python-2.7

My python script is behaving in a for me not understandable fashion. It is a fairly complex script, which I am minimizing here for the sake of simplicity, hope to keep all important features here.

To the problem: I am trying to simulate several experimental curves with a common set of parameters. First of all, I calculate, from the input parameters two functions, SLD1 and SLD2, which will be used to determine the experimental curves.

```
Phi1, Phi2, SLD1, SLD2 = nr.Par(fit_params, Files, GFP, coher)
```

SLD1 and SLD2 have the same dimensions, but have different values. As said, from SLD1 and SLD2 I calculate the experimental curves and store them in the 5th column of an array (datax and datay).

```
for i in range(len(Files)):
   qexp, RRexp, RRerr, qres = np.loadtxt(Files[i], unpack=True, skiprows=24, usecols=(0,1,2,3))
   dataset = np.zeros(shape=(len(qexp),5))
   dataset[:,0:4] = np.column_stack((qexp*10, RRexp, RRerr, qres*10))
   data.append(dataset)

Phi1, Phi2, SLD1, SLD2 = nr.Par(fit_params, Files, GFP, coher)
datax = np.copy(data, order='K')
datay = np.copy(data, order='K')        
for i in range(len(Files)):
    q = data[i][:,0]
    datax[i][:,4] = np.copy(nr.NRcalc(q, SLD1[:,i,:],GFP))
    datay[i][:,4] = np.copy(nr.NRcalc(q, SLD2[:,i,:],GFP))
print(SLD2[:,1,:]- SLD1[:,1,:])
print(nr.NRcalc(data[1][:,0], SLD1[:,1,:], GFP)-nr.NRcalc(data[1][:,0], SLD2[:,1,:],GFP))
print(datax[1][:,4]-datay[1][:,4])
```

In my conception of the program, in datax[i][:,4] the experimental curve, calculated using SLD1 should be stored, and in datay[i][:,4] that using SLD2. However, the two columns are identical! In fact,

```
print(datax[1][:,4]-datay[1][:,4])
```

returns an array of zeros. In fact, when calculating datay[i][:,4] I am also overwriting datax[i][:,4]. What I cannot understand is why,

```
 print(nr.NRcalc(data[1][:,0], SLD1[:,1,:], GFP)-nr.NRcalc(data[1][:,0], SLD2[:,1,:],GFP))
```

returns the correct values. I have inserted maybe too much np.copy commands, hoping to solve the problem, which seems to be to an unwanted linking of arrays. However, this did not change anything to the output. For the sake of completeness, I post also the Nr.Calc function:

```
 def NRcalc(q,SLDt,GFP):
   start = timeit.default_timer()
   RR = np.ndarray(shape=(len(q)))
   x = SLDt[:,0]
   for j in range(len(q)):
    k0 = np.complex256(q[j]/2.+np.sqrt(4*np.pi*GFP[6]+0j))
    k = np.complex256(np.sqrt(k0**2-4*np.pi*SLDt[:,1]+0j))
    rij = np.zeros(shape=(len(x),1),dtype=np.complex_)
    Rij = np.zeros(shape=(len(x),1),dtype=np.complex_)

    for i in range(len(x)):
        if (i == len(x)-1):
            rij[i] = (k0-k[i])/(k[i]+k0)

        elif (i < len(x)-1):
            rij[i] = (k[i+1]-k[i])/(k[i]+k[i+1])

        Rij[0] = rij[0]

        if (i>0):
            pp = np.exp(-2j*k[i-1]*(x[i]-x[i-1])) #Phase shift of reflected wave
            Rij[i] = ((rij[i] + Rij[i-1]*pp)/(1+rij[i]*Rij[i-1]*pp))
        Ref=(Rij[len(x)-1])*np.conj(Rij[len(x)-1])
    RR[j]=Ref.real
   stop = timeit.default_timer()
   print("Time taken to calculate RR", stop-start)
   return RR+GFP[9]
```

What I am missing here? Thanks in advance for all help and suggestions.

Comment: The three `print` statements always check only the second file of data (index `1` instead of `i`); in the first iteration `datax` and `datay` _should_ be the same for that index.

Comment: Yes, I used the value of 1 only to avoid all three matrices printed, but the situation is identical for all values of i (and the print statements were out of the loop, sorry for the formatting error here.)